# Live upgrade RAM assigned to VM

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine

does anyone knows if it's possible to live upgrade machine type or RAM assigned to a VM on GCE so there's no downtime in case one needs additional resources ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no option for a live upgrade of the machine type or RAM, except during Google maintenance, however you can delete your instance without deleting the persistent disk and then create a new instance choosing the correct CPU type and RAM with this persistent disk. The process is fast and won't cause any loss of data.

Hope this helps.

Mary

Comment: Be careful when deleting your instance - if the "Auto delete boot disk" option was chosen while it was created, your root disk will be deleted too. Take a snapshot of the disk before deleting the instance if you are unsure and want to be safe.